# Why does Angular 2 use decorators?

Tags: angular, decorator, angular-decorator

I just started using Angular 2 and was wondering why some properties like `selector` and `template` are put in components decorators and not in components classes.

What's the point of using all these decorators in Angular 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To make it easy for tools to provide all kinds of support in templates like:

  - error checking
  - auto-completion
  - graphical GUI designers
- To generate code from decorators which allows:

  - to define some things more declaratively or
  - generate different code depending on some configuration (like the <strike>upcoming</strike> offline template compiler does)

Code would need to be executed to use results expressions might emit. Decorators can be easily evaluated statically without executing the TypeScript code (except maybe a simple and limited subset).

Comment: Could you elaborate upon why decorators make it easy for tools to provide support in templates? Aren't decorators just JavaScript functions? How does the decorator syntax change things?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the platform-specific answers already there, I'd love to chip in from a more generic view. This question, from my opinion, is somehow related to the decision of choosing decorator pattern over inheritance (e.g. `@Component` vs `extends Component`)

Some of the benefits of using decorators are:

**1. Separation of concerns:**

Information inside decorators is declarative, they define the behaviour of a class, most likely won't change over time and are used by the framework. Class properties and fields are class-specific data, will always be processed and frequently updated, and only are meaningful within the class itself. These two kinds of data should not be mixed together.

**2. Support multiple modifications**

Many languages prevent multiple inheritance due to [Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). On the other hands, one class can have multiple decorators for different purposes (e.g. `@Component` and the deprecated `@RouteConfig`)

Comment: I don't really buy the second argument. Where in a Angular2 does using decorators alleviate a multiple inheritance issue? Yeah, decorators are good for marking classes up with meta data. But they've used em like class/type declarations. Components classes/types are always dressed up with \@Component. Modules always with \@NgModule, and it doesn't make sense to put \@Component on anything other than what is a logical Component class etc. IMHO it is a dubious design decision. Not to say there aren't advantages - same as anything.

Answer (score 1):

In general, decorators allow you to execute functions. For example `@Component` executes the `Component` function imported from Angular2. Under the hood, such decorators define some metadata on the class. This allows you to configure the class to "flag" it as a component. Angular2 is then able to link selectors in templates to such class.

This article could give you more hints about what happens under the hood:

- https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7#.ryvc6ewsc

You can notice that decorators can apply in TypeScript at different levels (class, class property, method parameter).

Comment: "In general, decorators allow you to execute functions". That is not very helpful. Programming languages let you "Execute functions" ...

Answer (score 0):

In angular, we create classes for everything like components, services, directives,

So, how does angular compiler compiles your code and transform it into scripts that are ready to be run in a browser? This happens because of decorators. In simple words, you can say decorators allow you to attach metadata with the typescript class using which angular knows whether that class is a component or directive or module or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Decorator marks a class as an Angular component and provides configuration which determines how the component should be processed, instantiated, and used at runtime. It provides various options to configure it such as selector, templateUrl, template, styleUrls, styles, providers etc.